# CSS Having two lists, sync their vertical scroll while allowing one to scroll horizontally

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have two lists where item i in list 1 is related to item i in list 2.

i want both lists to be scrollable vertically, so that items i always have the same scrolling position in both lists.

But list 2 has more content for a screen to display (like a timeline of sorts), so I want that list to be scrollable horizontally (Mind you not the item itself but the whole list), while list 1 stays fixed.

Is there any way to do this in CSS only?

This is what I have so far:

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-snow-0ydmj)

**Please note that this is just illustrating the point**. The actual items are much bigger DOM structures and not just text.
I updated the codesandbox to illustrate the point.

I can't really seem to get the horizontal scrolling working. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Your codesandbox is not opening. Please check it once.

Comment: Not able to access ur codesandbox link, it says some error occurred.

Comment: Sorry, accidentally cropped a letter. Now it's working.

Comment: So you've been able to answer your question by yourself? Mark it as answered, please.

Comment: No that was referring to the codesandbox of couse.

Comment: Use white-space:nowrap; ?

Comment: I updated the codesandbox example to illustrate that I am not talking about text but "randomly" arranged structures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `width` to some appropriate large value (eg. `500px`) and also set `white-space: nowrap` on the `.rightPaneItem`.

Keep in mind that value of the `width` property on the `.rightPaneItem` element will need to be adjusted according to the content of the `rightPaneItem` that has the longest content.

```js
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="leftPane">
        LeftPane
        {new Array(100).fill(0).map((_, i) => (
          <div key={i} class="leftPaneItem">
            item {i}
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
      <div className="rightPane">
        RightPane
        {new Array(100).fill(0).map((_, i) => (
          <div key={i} class="rightPaneItem">
            item {i} with a way longer text so you should be able to scroll
            horizontally
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}


ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```css
.App {
  text-align: center;
  max-height: 300px;
  max-width: 300px;
  display: flex;
  border: 3px dashed green;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 5px;
}

.leftPane {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  flex: 1;
  border: 2px solid red;
  padding: 5px;
}

.rightPane {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  flex: 2;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  padding: 5px;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.leftPaneItem {
  height: 20px;
}

.rightPaneItem {
  height: 20px;
  width: 500px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

#### Edit:

Since you will have the content with variable length in the right column, you could use the following approach.

Instead of setting the `width` and `overflow` properties on `.rightPaneItem`, you could add `overflow: auto` on the outer container `.App` and `.rightPane` element.

```js
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="leftPane">
        LeftPane
        {new Array(100).fill(0).map((_, i) => (
          <div key={i} class="leftPaneItem">
            item {i}
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
      <div className="rightPane">
        RightPane
        {new Array(100).fill(0).map((_, i) => {
          if (i % 2 == 0) {
             return (
               <div key={i} class="rightPaneItem">
                  item {i} with a way longer text so you should be able to scroll
            horizontally
              </div>);
          } else {
             return (
               <div key={i} class="rightPaneItem">
                  item {i} with a way longer text so you should be able to scroll
            horizontally.                   item {i} with a way longer text so you should be able to scroll
            horizontally.                   item {i} with a way longer text so you should be able to scroll
            horizontally
              </div>);
          }
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}


ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```css
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  max-height: 300px;
  max-width: 300px;
  display: flex;
  border: 3px dashed green;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 5px;
}

.leftPane {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  flex: 1;
  border: 2px solid red;
  padding: 5px;
}

.rightPane {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  flex: 2;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  padding: 5px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.leftPaneItem {
  height: 20px;
}

.rightPaneItem {
  height: 20px;
  position: relative;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

I have also created a demo on codesandbox that is similar to the one posted in your question and uses the same CSS as the one used in second code snippet.

[image: Edit keen-dijkstra-mzxk4]

Comment: Ok, maybe I should elaborate the the items in the lists aren't just text, but much bigger DOM structures.

Comment: I updated the codesandbox example to illustrate that I am not talking about text but "randomly" arranged structures.

Comment: See the updated answer. Codesandbox demo included in the answer uses the blocks that you used in the updated codesandbox demo in your question.